# Whether the OSPF ABR Router's loopback network should announce to Backbone Area?

Tags: router, ospf

The OSPF ABR Router whether its loopback network should announce to Backbone Area?

[image]

the upper snapshot shows the C,D,E are ABR Routers, if everyone has its own loopback networks, I want to know whether they must be announce to the Backbone Area? or if not unnecessary, whether we announce to Backbone habitually?

Comment: What do you need a loopback interface for?

Comment: it can be the OSPF router's `route-id`.

Comment: A router ID is not an IP address; it just looks like one because both are 32-bit numbers represented in dotted decimal notation. That being said, network admins can choose to match the router ID with a loopback IP address for easier troubleshooting.